# i3-wm clipboard is cleared when I close a window

Tags: clipboard, i3

I'm using i3 and normally I can copy text between windows no problem but if I close the window where the text is copied from before pasting the clipboard seems to get cleared.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Update: Found that this happens with terminal but not with firefox.

Comment: Does this happen with every application that you copied text from? I sometimes experience similar behaviour, but I think it's only a few applications that do this.

Comment: @wieland I think you're right because I only noticed with terminal and now that I try with Firefox it should.

Answer (score 5):

I found out that having a clipboard manager application (like `clipit`) fixes this issue.

Comment: That's true. Just to give reasoning to it: Managing a clipboard is not the job of a window manager, but of a clipboard manager.